# Deserializing JSON to Python object and serializing it again later (JSON contains key "class")

Tags: python, json

I want to deserialize some JSON from a RESTful api in Python.
BUT: the JSON has a key named class...

Example (groups.json):

```
"1": {  
    "name": "Hello"
    "class": "stuff"
}
```

How do I deserialize that into an Object? since "class" is a keyword...

I tried:

```
class Group(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, class: str):
        self.name = name
        self.class=class
```

I also want to serialize it again later and it HAS TO HAVE the same keys as in the beginning.

greetings

Comment: The snippet you posted isn't valid json.  There's no reason, however, that Python can't process json with the string `"class"` as a key.

Comment: This is not an issue, you can have strings as keys in dicts even if they are a reserved word: `json.loads('{"1": {"class": "Bedroom"}}')` <-- no problem. What you *can't* do is use reserved words as identifiers: `class = "hello"` <-- syntax error.

Comment: @MarkM yes. that is exactly what I'd need to do...
as I do want to serialize it again later (after stuff has happend) and I cannot rename that "class" key...
is there a way around that?

Comment: @ChristianBley it's not clear what the problem is. You should edit the question showing precisely what you are trying to do in a way that others can reproduce. Currently the answer to your question as posed is to pass the string to `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 0):

First the python [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) by default deserialize json data into a dictionary. Dictionary keys can be of whatever (hashable) type in this case strings. So when you pull out the "class" data you would simply pull it out with the string literal:

```py
import json

content = '{ "1": { "class": "Bedroom" } }'
dictionary = json.loads(content)

clazz = dictionary["1"]["class"]
```

Now the variable you are setting the value to cannot be named `class` because it is as you say a keyword. A common convention is to you `clazz` instead for languages with this keyword.

If you are looking to truly deserialize the json into a class look into defining your own [`JsonDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders), a simple implementation could be:

```py
import json

class Room:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class RoomDecoder(json.JsonDecoder):
    def decode(self, s):
        dictionary = json.loads(s)
        name = dictionary["1"]["class"]

        return Room(name)
```